# Super fast downvoting (Moderator attention requested)

Tags: support, down-votes

I just asked [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/is-killing-family-different-from-killing-friends-how-do-i-interpret-this-quest), and it got a downvote so fast that I sincerely don't even know how the person was able to do it.

The downvote came before I even saw the question appear in the main list of question. I was even refreshing to see when the question came up, because I wanted to make sure the title appeared correctly.

I seriously question if any human could have actually read any of it at all in that time.

This seems to be part of a general pattern of downvoting, similar to [this issue](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/857/retaliatory-downvoting-moderator-attention-requested). It's retaliatory downvoting based on something else other than the actual content of the question. (I have suspicions on who and why, but since I can't prove anything, it's best left unsaid.)

I'm requesting moderator attention. If it is possible to tell if it's the same person who downvoted in the other questions linked to in my other request, then surely this is indicitive of behaviour not appropriate for the site.

Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Sounds like somebody hates manga?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't voted on that question yet, but I've been able to fully read and vote on a post within fifteen seconds of it being posted before. Remember that there is some caching on the main question lists, so you don't necessarily see changes immediately, but someone just visiting the site might have found the question and voted on it.

Also, sometimes people just read the title and the first paragraph or two and then vote if they don't like the question.

The best way to get moderator attention is to actually just flag your own question and use the "other" reason.  Moderators typically can't discuss actions taken in public anyway, so that's the recommended way to deal with suspected problem users.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about flagging. I thought flagging was just for when the question itself was problematic, not reactions to the question. But I'll do what you recommend from now on.